# Add Namepace to unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I try to use the following class in Unity
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=net-6.0

So my Code is simply:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;


public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    IEnumerator Start()
    {

        using (ECDiffieHellmanCng alice = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
        { }
}
```

Unity responds like :
Assets\Scripts\TcpClientAsyncBehaviour.cs(27,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ECDiffieHellmanCng' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So i got the nugget File from here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng/6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7
made it a zip file and extracted the System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll from lib/netstandard2.0 and put it into unity.
Nothing changed.

I also tried the UnityNuget package but it refuses to install the nugget I would need.
I also tried to use an rsp File with the content -r:System.Security.dll and copied it into Unity still nothing.

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure it’s compatible with unity? Not everything is

Comment: So if its not campatible there is no way to use it in unity ? I thought there might be a workaround